# while reading the file through python, prints file printed successfully after each printed line but after one empty line, why?

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am trying to learn python in this lockdown. I am completely new to programming. I am practicing to read a file. The code used with the results is in the first screenshot. I noticed that after every line it reads and prints from the file it prints the statement file printed successfully. But prints that after one empty line. So, if the file which has to be read has an empty line it prints an empty line, and then after one more empty line, it prints file printed successfully. Is it possible to print the file printed successfully exactly below the printed line without any blank line? Could you please help me out? I am stuck in this.
The code used is below:

```
fileptr = open(r"C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\untitled\Day1.py")
for line in fileptr.readlines():
    if '#' in line:
        print(line)
print("file is opened successfully")
```

Answer (score 0):

*Didn't quite get what u want to do, but here I go.*

Okay so, what's happening here is that in the text file whenever u proceeds to next line for that there's a '**\n**' which tells python it's a new line and since you are in a loop puts the '**\n**' in a new line leaving blank space therefore, you must be getting a blank line. The indentation is not clear but if u want the "**printed successfully**" to be printed just once then this statement should be out of the '**for loop**'.

To print "**print sucessfully**" after each line but without an empty line you can use a method called '**.rstrip()**' inside which u can give the parameter '**\n**'(*using the inverted commas*). This will remove the "**\n**" from each line that will be printed.